# Where do I find a list of officially supported mimetypes for Android?

Tags: android, mime-types

I found out that on Android contacts, at least HTC Sense stores Facebook ID with the following mimetype: `vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.facebook.profile` this differs from their mimetype format such as `com.htc.socialnetwork.facebook/smallavatar`

I am wondering where do I find a list of officially supported mimetypes for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "officially supported mimetypes for Android" except to the extent they are documented in random spots in the Android SDK, usually as `CONTENT_TYPE` public static data members (e.g., `android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE`).

To the best of my knowledge, there is no HTC Sense SDK, and therefore there are no "officially supported mimetypes for Android" related to anything in any version of Sense.